# Spring batch job execution context and step execution context clarification needed

Tags: spring-batch

I am using spring batch 3.0.3 and need some clarification about not serializing job execution context and step execution context as this we have large object sets and we dont want to persist them in spring batch tables. Is there anyway we can just store short_context and not serialized object?

Answer (score 1):

By default, no because the `ExecutionContext` provides the data required for restartability.  If you *must* do this (I'd encourage a different design), you'd have to implement your own `ExecutionContextDao`.

That being said, I'd encourage you not to go this route and to store your large object somewhere else.  Even a Spring bean that is a Map that you want to use as a cache that is not maintained by the framework would be a better option IMHO.